# Whats the scope of const and how to measure it?

Tags: performance, dart, memory-management, constants

Lets say you have a class `Bird` that has a const constructor:

```dart
class Bird { 
  const Bird();      
  void fly() {}
}
```

You need to use it in a place but you have two options:

1.

```dart
const bird = Bird();
void doIt() {
  bird.fly();
}
```

2. 

```dart
void doIt2() {
  const bird = Bird();
  bird.fly();
}
```

## Questions :)

- Whats the of `const` constructors? it will avoid the creation of the objects in both examples?
- Is there any difference between *1.* and *2.* related to `const`?

> Im thinking that there are no difference in terms of performance but Im not really sure how to measure it

- How can I measure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in the value or the efficiency of accessing it.

The only difference is that in version 1, other code can refer to the `bird` variable, and in version 2, it's a local variable inside the function, and cannot be seen from the outside.

Just like any other variable, its scope is defined by where it's declared, not what its value is.
It doesn't matter, for that purpose, whether it's a `const` variable or not.

Because it *is* a `const` variable, it also means that the value is computed at compile-time, so accessing it takes no time at runtime.
There is nothing to measure, because accessing a constant variable at runtime, no matter where it is, just means loading a reference to the already existing value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how your response relates to `const`?

Comment: The `const` is not important to the scope of a variable. Because the variable is a `const` variable, there is no difference in how the variable behaves either. Otherwise a top-level variable would be lazy and a local variable would be eager, but for constants, they're all computed at compile-time anyway, which is why there is also no difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

- In the first example you have an instance variable. Instance variables are variables that are defined in the class, for which each instantiated object of that class has a separate copy or instance of the variables.
- In the second example you have a local variable. After the calculate function executes, the local variables will no longer exist except of cases of closures.

By the way.

Use final for local variables that are not reassigned and var for those that are.

Use var for all local variables, even ones that aren’t reassigned. Never use final for locals. (Using final for fields and top-level variables is still encouraged, of course.)

https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how your response relates to `const`?